# What does 着 mean in 「六時着」 and in 「六着」?

Tags: kanji, counters

One of the kanji we recently learned in class was 着. We learned it could be used for **to wear** [着]{き}る, **to arrive** [着]{つ}く, and as either a "classifier for arrival" or a "counter for jacket".

In our homework, we have the following 2:

1. [六]{ろく}[時]{じ}[着]{ちゃく}
2. [六]{ろく}[着]{ちゃく}

I am not sure how the classifier and counter work. This is what I think they mean:

1. 6 o'clock arrival (like as in an appointment)
2. 6th arrival (as in the 6th person to arrive) **or** 6 jackets

Is this the correct way to use the kanji?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. I think it's usually more obvious, especially when they appear in paragraphs.

Comment: Does 6着 really mean '6th arrival' ?

Comment: Yes. You see this used a lot in a race.

Comment: Then how do you say `6 arrivals`?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what the English phrase "6 arrivals" means. Can you make an example sentence that's a bit longer?

Comment: 例え、飛行機は6便あって、飛行機の到着の数は６つになりますが着を使って数うことはありかどうかという質問です。

Comment: 着 as counter is only applicable to cloths, I think. If you are counting the total number of arrivals of something, you'd be using the counter appropriate for that something, as in 便 for airlines and 本 for buses/trains, etc.